# Parameterize pytest using fixture loaded from database

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, parameterized-tests

I'm trying to use pytest to take in an id for a suite to run, load the suite from a db, and then generate the test cases in a parameterized fashion. The code below shows the gist of what I want to do, but errors with `fixture 'case' not found`.

How can I parameterize `case` with the ids that get returned from the db lookup?

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "test_harness.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()

from unitrunner.models import TestSuiteModel as SuiteModel


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--suite", action="append", default=[],
        help="Suite ID to evaluate")


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'suite' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        suite_id = metafunc.fixturenames['suite']

        this_suite = SuiteModel.objects.get(id=suite_id)
        test_cases = this_suite.testCases.all()

        metafunc.parametrize(
            "case",
            [item.id for item in test_cases]
        )


def test_case(case):
    print(case)

    assert False
```

Answer (score 1):

`fixture 'case' not found` means that the parametrization did not happen: the line

```
metafunc.parametrize(
    "case",
    [item.id for item in test_cases]
)
```

was not executed. This is no suprise because you don't use the fixture `suite` in the `test_case`, thus `if 'suite' in metafunc.fixturenames` will return `False`. If you actually use the fixture in `test_case`, for example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def suite():
    pass

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('suite')
def test_case(case):
    print(case)

    assert False
```

the test will be correctly parametrized. Btw, the `suite` fixture in my example is working as a marker and should be better reworked to one:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    try:
        suite_id = getattr(metafunc.function, 'suite')
    except AttributeError:  # no suite marker
        pass
    else:
        this_suite = SuiteModel.objects.get(id=suite_id)
        test_cases = this_suite.testCases.all()

        metafunc.parametrize(
            "case",
            [item.id for item in test_cases]
        )
```

Now simply mark the relevant tests:

```
@pytest.mark.suite(1)
def test_case(case):
    assert case == 1
```